# Black line at the top of the screen

Tags: android, xml

what is happening to me is pretty tricky...I have this xml file as a layout for the adapter of a list view object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/exBackGround"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/exBackGround" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/exBackGround"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblFolderName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/exBackGround"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/exForeGround" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/exBackGround"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="100"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/exForeGround" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/exGradEnd" >
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't understand why, this layout results in what it is expecetd to do, plus a black line at the top that I can't understand where it cames from. Unfortunately, as a new user, I can0t post the image, sorry.

Comment: could you paste the colors please?

Comment: sorry didn't see your answer, I can't paste the image as I am a new user unfortunately. If you meant the values of the resources color, here we go: exBackGround = #FEFEFE, exForeGround = #101010, exGradEnd=#A0A0A0

Comment: Ok problem solved, I auto-answer my self in the case someone else will need it in the future. The black line seen in the graphical layout in eclipse was fake, just coming from my "type of display" selection on the top. The black line I was seeing in the final app, was the default divider for the ListView. To make it disappear, I have just set lv.setDividerHeight(0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved, I auto-answer my self in the case someone else will need it in the future. The black line seen in the graphical layout in eclipse was fake, just coming from my "type of display" selection on the top. The black line I was seeing in the final app, was the default divider for the ListView. To make it disappear, I have just set lv.setDividerHeight(0).